# How to add objects to InputFilter, does it have some kind of factory?

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

My InputFilter:

```
namespace FarmAccounts\InputFilter;

use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;

class Account extends InputFilter
{
    public function init()
    {
        $factory = $this->getFactory();

        $owner = $factory->createInput(array(
            'name' => 'owner',
            'required' => true,
            'validators' => array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'DoctrineModule\Validator\NoObjectExists',
                    'options' => array(
                        'object_repository' => $entityManager->getRepository('OAuth2Server\Entity\User'),
                        'fields' => 'id'
                    )
                )
            )
        ));
        $this->add($owner);
    }
}
```

then when I need this filter I call:

```
$filter = $this->serviceManager->get('InputFilterManager')
             ->get('FarmAccounts\InputFilter\Account');
```

As you can see `$entityManager` is not defined anywhere and thats my problem I don't know how to add it here. InputFilter doesn't have service locator. maybe there is a way to create factory for inputfitler?

UPDATE:

I have tried to implement `ServiceLocatorAwareInterface` but as it doesn't go throught service manager it was not set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I managed solve my problem

factory:

```
namespace FarmAccounts\Factory;

use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use FarmAccounts\InputFilter\Account as AccountInputFilter;

class AccountInputFilterFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $input_filter = new AccountInputFilter;

        $entityManager = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');

        $input_filter->setEntityManager($entityManager);

        return $input_filter;
    }
}
```

and module.config.php:

```
'input_filters' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'FarmAccounts\InputFilter\Account' => 'FarmAccounts\Factory\AccountInputFilterFactory',
    ),
),
```